# Why is the lattice decoding problem NP-hard?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, vector-lattices

Given an alphabet $\mathbb{A}$ and a lattice $L = \{Y : Y = Hx, X \in \mathbb{A}^n\}$, the lattice decoding problem is to find:
$$  \hat{x} = \text{argmin } \| Z - Hx \| $$

Where Z is some vector $\in \mathcal{R}^n$.
I read that it is NP-hard to solve for the ML solution. Can someone explain why? Can one not simply find $x_1 = H^{-1}Z $ and quantize the result, coordinate by coordinate onto the alphabet $\mathbb{A}$?

Comment: You meant $L = \{ Hm, m \in \mathbb{Z}^n \}$ for some $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \det(H) \ne 0$. We can also look at lattices in $\mathbb{C}$. The simplest case is $L =\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}= \{ u+iv, (u,v) \in \mathbb{Z}^2\}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z} =\{ (au+bv)+i (cu+dv), (u,v) \in \mathbb{Z}^2\}$ iff $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}^4, ad-bc = \pm 1$, ie. $HM$ generates the same lattice as $H$ iff $M \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$. Do you see how $M$ affects $(HM)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @reuns so if I understand what you are trying to say, now the underlying vectors $m$ would no longer map to the same points on the lattice when considering $HM$ (it would now map to $M^{-1}m$). But now while quantizing $(HM)^{-1}Y$, we could get a different vector from the ML solution ($M^{-1}\hat{x}$) assuming that the quantized $H^{-1}Y$ did give the ML solution ($\hat{x}$)?

Comment: Yes. The idea really is that many different basis (columns of $H$) give the same lattice. The quantization works when the basis  is (almost) orthogonal, that's why the LLL-algorithm attempts to find an almost orthogonal basis.